# Calculate an integral with $\sin$?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

How can I calculate the following integral?
$$
\int \left[ \sin((x+x_0)T)\times\sin((x-x_0)T) \right]^{2n} \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

where $x_0$ and $T$ are constants.

Please help, thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You could try to take various restrictions on the constants and use complex analysis.

Comment: Hint: $\sin (\alpha + \beta) \sin (\alpha - \beta) = \sin^2 \alpha - \sin^2 \beta$

Comment: thanks pseudonym, you are right, but we have power 2n in this integrator

Comment: If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you. Also, in future you should write your question in [MathJaX](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), as it is much nicer and easier to read. I have edited this question for you though.

Comment: i am sorry, i am new in this forum

Answer (score 2):

By the Briggs' formulas,
$$\sin((x+x_0)T)\cdot\sin((x-x_0)T) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\cos(2x_0T)-\cos(2xT)\right),\tag{1}$$
hence, by the binomial theorem:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\int\left[\sin((x+x_0)T)\cdot\sin((x-x_0)T)\right]^{2n}dx\\ = \frac{1}{4^n}\sum_{j=0}^{2n}\binom{2n}{j}(-1)^j\cos^{2n-j}(2x_0 T)\int \cos^j(2Tx)\,dx\end{eqnarray*}\tag{2}$$
In order to compute the innermost integral, we can use the binomial theorem again:
$$\cos^j(2Tx) = \frac{1}{2^j}\left(e^{2Tix}+e^{-2Tix}\right)^j,$$
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\cos^j(2Tx) &=& \frac{1}{2^j}\sum_{k=0}^j\binom{j}{k} e^{2T(j-2k)ix}\\&=&\frac{2}{2^j}\sum_{k<j/2}\binom{j}{k}\cos(2T(j-2k)x)+\left\{\begin{array}{rc}0&\text{if j is odd}\\\frac{1}{2^j}\binom{j}{j/2}&\text{if j is even}\end{array}\right.\end{eqnarray*}\tag{3}$$
so, integrating:
$$\int\cos^j(2Tx)\,dx\\=\frac{2}{2^j}\sum_{k<j/2}\binom{j}{k}\frac{\sin(2T(j-2k)x)}{2T(j-2k)}+\left\{\begin{array}{rc}0&\text{if j is odd}\\\frac{1}{2^j}\binom{j}{j/2}x&\text{if j is even.}\end{array}\right.\tag{4}$$
As the last step, plug $(4)$ into $(2)$.

Comment: May I dare to ask the reason of the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter but you do make some sign errors start at your formula for $\cos^j(2Tx)$,

Comment: @achillehui: Ok, I wrote $k-2j$ in place of $j-2k$. Is it ok now?

Comment: The biggest problem is $\cos(2Tx) = \frac12 \left( e^{i2Tx} \color{red}{+} e^{-i2Tx}\right)$

Comment: @achillehui: Thank you so much, now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the sinusoidal function to exponential function. Then it is much easier to do the indefinite integral.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.